# pl/sql input options

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there a way to ask the user, which option he want for a procedure; like it is ask for abc here

`create or replace procedure Test3 (abc in abc.abc%type)`

so if an user starts a procedure, the system should ask: do you want to add an employee or do you only want to change the job_id of an existing employee

Comment: Presumably, there is some application that the user is running that has connected to the database in order to run the procedure.  It would be that front-end application that would prompt the user to determine what they wanted to do.  It seems unlikely that it would make sense for a single procedure to both add an employee and change the `job_id` of an employee.  It would make much more sense to have two different procedures and for the front end to call whichever procedure was needed passing whatever parameters are needed.

Comment: Thanks Justin for answering! Unfortunately I have to make one procedure for both (it's a demo instruction for our imminent test in school). Do you know any other way to solv this (without application?) thanks!

Comment: How is the procedure being called?  You can't call a procedure without an application.  That application could be as small as, say, a SQL*Plus script with an `ACCEPT` command and some substitution variables.

Comment: Sorry, I just started learning. We always add a procedure with "create or replace procedure abc as ..." with the Oracle Sql Developer

Comment: Are you then executing the procedure via SQL Developer?  SQL Developer can act as a client application and supports much of the syntax that `SQL*Plus` supported to build small scripts that run on the client, prompt for input, and then pass that as parameters to a procedure or that call one of two procedures depending on the input.  The stored procedure runs on the database server and cannot interact with the user-- the stored procedure can't prompt for data.

Comment: Hi, according to my understanding of your requirement  you want  a menu driven program.. this can be done using a single procedure only.. you can take input parameter  a flag variable... and according to that flag write block of code that will insert/Update you tables..

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL is not an interactive language. You must use some front end to call PL/SQL procedure for passing the user input from front end.

Yet you can write PL/SQL block containing `substitute variable &` that asks for input at compile time but not runtime. So you can provide input every time you compile it.

```
DECLARE  
  name  := &user_input_name  
BEGIN  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name: '||name);  
END;
```